# How do I free the memory occupied by variable that is being returned (using C++, in a class, destructor)?

Tags: c++, malloc, free

Example code:

```
class Myclass
{
    char * function(const char *x, const char *y)
    {
        char *a, *b, *c;
        *a = strdup(x);
        *b = strdup(y);
        *c = (char *) malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
        ...
        ...
        free(a);
        free(b);
        return c;
    }
};
```

How do I `free` the memory occupied by `c`? When I try to do it in the destructor, it says `use of undeclared identifier c`.
Is there anyway to free the memory without allocating the memory in a constructor?

Comment: In practice, avoid using raw C pointers. You should use `std::string` as the type of arguments and results to your `function`. You need to read a good book on C++11

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ code? And `strdup`? Why not `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `class destructor` should only be responsible for freeing the memory allocated by `constructors for that class`. That's what is ownership.

Also, `c` in your code is local to `function` so it ceases to exist beyond that function i.e a sure shot memory leak unless you are returning `c` from this `function` and making sure that caller calls `delete/free` on that memory. But this puts much burden on `usability` department.

Answer (score 2):

answer: stop!

and remember you're writing in c++ where the correct thing to do is leave memory management to the standard library and return values rather than pointers.

```
class Myclass
{
    std::string function(const char *x, const char *y)
    {
        // no more overhead than strdup - and much safer!
        std::string a(x), b(y);

        // what I shall return
        std::string c;

        // un-necessary, but can improve efficiency
        c.reserve(a.size() + b.size());

        // perform my complex string algorithm
        //... for example, concatenate into c:
        c = a + b;

        // return my result    
        return c;
    }
};
```

now call like so:

```
{
  MyClass x;
  auto s = x.function("hello", "world");

  // s is a std::string. if I *really* want a pointer, I can...
  const char* p = s.c_str();

  // note: no need to free *anything*
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already accepted another answer a few days ago. So, I have only upvoted your answer. I will update the class to use `string` datatype soon. Thank you again!

Comment: Why did you use `auto`? Isn't it `auto` by default?

Comment: the meaning of auto changed in c++11. It means 'deduce the type from the right hand side of the assignment'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `free(c);` in the destructor unless `c` is a member variable, which is what the compiler is telling you.

In this case, you have to make sure that the caller of `MyClass::function` calls `free` on the returned value.